# Does a total preorder on lotteries that preserves countable mixtures preserve arbitrary mixtures?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, order-theory, convexity

Let $X$ be a countable set. A *lottery on $X$* is a function $\lambda: X \to [0,1]$ such that $\sum_x \lambda(x) = 1$. Let $\Delta X$ be the set of lotteries on $X$.

A *total preorder* $\preceq$ on $\Delta X$ is a transitive, reflexive, complete binary relation on $\Delta X$.

Let $(I, \mathcal I)$ be a measurable space. Note that if $\lambda_i$ is a family of lotteries on $X$ indexed by $I$ and $p$ is a probability measure on $(I, \mathcal I)$, then the function $\int\lambda_ip(di)$ on $X$ defined by $\big(\int\lambda_ip(di)\big)(x) = \int \lambda_i(x)p(di)$ is a lottery on $X$.

Let $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ be families of lotteries on $X$ indexed by $I$. The total preorder $\preceq$ is *discretely mixing* just in case if $\lambda_i \preceq \mu_i$ for all $i \in I$, then $\int \lambda_i p(di) \preceq \int\mu_ip(di)$ for all discrete probabilities $p$ on $(I, \mathcal I)$.

**Question.** If $\preceq$ is discretely mixing, then is $\preceq$ *totally mixing* in the following sense: If $\lambda_i \preceq \mu_i$ for all $i \in I$, then $\int \lambda_i p(di) \preceq \int \mu_i p(di)$ for all probability measures on $(I, \mathcal I)$?

I suspect the answer is negative, but have not found a counterexample.